# Use VBA to create histogram for each worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I am trying to create a histogram for each worksheet in a workbook. In each worksheet, I have these two columns of values:
(1) the Input Range (the data I want to analyze), represented by "pasteRange"in my code.
(2) the Bin Range (the interval I want to use for the analysis), represented by "pasteRange2" in my code.

I hope to:
Create both the histogram table and histogram graph. The table should be located at cell AK23 and the graph should be spanning N2:S20 in each worksheet.
The code I have so far does not generate the table and whenever I run it a window pops up and asks me to press OK to overwrite data. If I keep pressing OK VBA would crash, and if I press Cancel, only the last worksheet generates the table. Only one chart has been created among the worksheets, and there is no data in it (the chart code is copied from running a macro)...

I am not a CS major and new to VBA - sorry if this question is silly and thank you very much for your help!

The code I tried so far is:

```
Dim I As Integer
Dim pasteRange As Range
Dim pasteRange2 As Range

WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For I = 8 to WS_Count

Set pasteRange = ...
Set pasteRange2 = ...(these are irrelevant so are excluded here)

Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Histogram", pasteRange, ActiveSheet.Range("$AK$23"), pasteRange2, False, False, True, False

ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementLeft -31.2
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementTop -1.2
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleWidth 1.3541666667, msoFalse, _
    msoScaleFromTopLeft

Next I
```

Comment: Try replacing `WS_Count` with `Sheets.Count`, and add a line, immediately after (very beginning of For Loop), that says `Sheets(I).Select`. Does that help fix the problem?  (Also is 8 the first sheet that should be looked at?)

Comment: @Demetri I just editted the post (forgot to put `WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count ` in.) I tried adding your suggestion `Sheets(I).Select `, but when I ran it Excel could not stop and crashed.. yes 8 is the first sheet to be looked at! Thanks,

Comment: Histograms can be easily created without using an actual Excel chart object.  Clever use of `rept()` and the pipe character `|` in bold 8pt Script font can make a solid bar.  It might be easier to use basic Excel formulas than to try to manipulate a chart with VBA.  Just an option.

Comment: Might help if you post code for `ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Histogram`

Comment: As per the following [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7ed39841-3502-4f69-9ded-ac41b102b99e/histogram-from-excel-vba),  just wondering if you enabled the "Analysis ToolPak - VBA" in Options > Add-Ins > Manage: Excel Add-Ins > Go?  Also you might try "stepping" through the macro, to test each line one at a time, to see if they work as expected.

Comment: @findwindow - I believe an add in is being called, so there is likely no code to post for this particular piece.

Comment: Oh didn't realize that was an addin XD

Comment: Yes exactly @Demetri - I have enabled the Analysis ToolPak, and ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Histogram is that add in. I think the problem is in the histogram line - it is a pity Excel does not tell me what exactly the problem is with that line...